# C++: Cannot make operator<< a friend of a templated nested class

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, friend

This is the basic code structure (I'll reveal more if it becomes relevant to the problem):

```cpp
class Outer {
    // Forward declaration for the next forward declaration
    template <class C> class Inner;

    // Forward declaration for the actual Inner class definition
    template <class C>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Inner<C> &obj);

    template <class C>
    class Inner {
        friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream &os, const Inner &obj);
    };
};
```

Since the inner class is templated, I realized my `operator<<` override had to be as well. Additionally, the second `friend` declaration is a template instantiation, so that `operator<< <C>` is only friends with `Outer::Inner<C>`.

When I define the operator override in the separate implementation file, it looks like this:

```cpp
template <class C>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Outer::Inner<C> &obj) {
    // definition
}
```

Over the past several days, I have repeatedly refactored my code to a ridiculous degree in the hopes of making this work. Most recently, I tried only compiling `*.h` on g++ and received three error messages all for the same line (the one with the template instantiation).

```cpp
outer.h:x:y1: error: declaration of ‘operator<<’ as non-function
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream &os, const Inner &obj);
                                 ^~
outer.h:x:y1: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
outer.h:x:y2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream &os, const Inner &obj);
                                    ^
```

Despite extensively searching the phrases given in the error output, however, I'm still no closer to solving this, so I'd be grateful if someone with C++ experience, who unlike me knows what they're doing, could please help.

Comment: Drop `<C>` in the definition - it's not a valid syntax. Further, templates must be defined in a header file; the compiler needs to see the definition at the point where the template is used.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I remember that when writing the definition for the inner class, I had to use `template <class C> Outer::Inner<C>::Inner() {/*...*/}` for the constructor, with similar lines for the member functions, so I must have gotten confused (should I remove `template <class C>` too?). Besides, the issues I saw just from compiling the header file would still remain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much more research, I am convinced that this specific case is actually *impossible*—an `operator` overload generally can't be a friend of a class that is both nested and templated. (If you think that's wrong, please let me know why, since I'm far from being a C++ expert myself.)

I've tried many, many different solutions to this, and while I don't think it would be very productive to write a detailed account of every method I tried and the specific reasons for their failures, some of the errors included

- invalid use of incomplete type `class Outer`
- field... has incomplete type `Outer::Inner<`[Type]`>`
- no match for `operator<<`
- ambiguous overload for `operator<<`

in addition to the ones in the original post.

So in this area of my code, I'm ditching the `operator<<` approach. My less elegant but immediately effective alternative:

```cpp
class Outer {
    template <class C>
    class Inner {
    public:
        std::ostream& printout(std::ostream &os) {
            os << /* whatever */ << /* I want */ << /* to print */;
            return os;
        }
    };
};
```

---

Some potentially helpful links:

- https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends
- https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=2017753&sid=8c7d68d4990924a1e4d794b4ed1af197#p2017753